# Sum all produced value of select query with union all and distinct using MS sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have produced data from a query having a distinct value of a date. Now what I want is to get the sum of the total days and put on the last row that is why I used a `UNION ALL`. The problem is how can I get the total sum of the days produced only by the query.

below is the query:

```
USE  ANR_Payroll
Select 
Distinct a.[from],
(Select top 1 [to] FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].[tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z where A.[From] =Z.[From] and A.employeecode = Z.EmployeeCode ) As 'TO',
'***' as 'Total Days Worked',
(Select top 1 Employeecode FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].    [tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z where A.[from] =Z.[from] and A.employeecode =     Z.EmployeeCode ) As 'Employeecode',
B.LastName,
B.FirstName,
B.Middlename,
B.Levelcode,
(Select top 1 z.[BatchCode] FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].    [tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z where A.[from] =Z.[from] and A.employeecode =     Z.EmployeeCode ) As 'BatchCode' ,
(Select top 1 Z.EarningCode FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].    [tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z where A.[from] =Z.[From] and A.employeecode = Z.EmployeeCode ) As 'Earning Code' ,
(Select top 1 Z.Rate FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].[tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z     where A.[from] =Z.[From] and A.employeecode = Z.EmployeeCode ) As 'Rate',
(Select top 1 Z.Ratetype FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].    [tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z where A.[from] =Z.[From] and A.employeecode =     Z.EmployeeCode ) As 'RateType',
(Select top 1 A.[noofunits] / 8 FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].    [tblPayrollTransactionEntry] Z where A.[from] =Z.[From] and A.employeecode =     Z.EmployeeCode ) as 'DAYS',
'' Tenure,
'A' Orderkey 
from 
   tblPayrolltransactionEntry as A 
   inner join 
   tblEmployeeMainInfo as B ON a.EmployeeCode = b.EmployeeCode 
  where B.Employeecode like '%0000011350%'and EarningCode = 'SF' and PayType     = 'PayOut'  
   UNION ALL 
 Select
    CASE when '' = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '**' END,
CASE when '' = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '**' END, 
'Total Days Worked', 
A.Employeecode,
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
(SUM(NoOfUNits) / 8) as 'DAYS',
((SUM(NoOfUNits) / 8) / 366) as 'Tenure',     
'B' Orderkey
from tblPayrolltransactionEntry as A 
inner join tblEmployeeMainInfo as B ON a.EmployeeCode = b.EmployeeCode 
where B.Employeecode like '%0000011350%'and EarningCode = 'SF' and PayType =     'PayOut'  
    Group by a.employeecode 
 ORDER by [Employeecode],Orderkey
```

---

Attached file is my output using that query.

The total is get from all the value without the using distinct
[image]

Comment: In almost all cases it is a very bad habit to *include* aggregating rows into the resultset. This is much better to be done on application level. Whereeve you are loading and displaying your data you will be able to to summation there...

Comment: sad to say sir Shnugo my application level is locked, i am trying to fix it the way how it generate reports  :(

Answer (score 0):

You really want to be doing this in the reporting layer of your report, it's not best practice to do this in SQL.

If you're are insistent that you need to do this in SQL however, then the approach that I would take would be to copy the original query and make it a subquery. You haven't mentioned how this is going to be ran, incase it's going to be a view I won't take the approach that would use temp tables.

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your query while doing this, you shouldn't be hitting tables like that in your SELECT query, it's completely unnecessary and will be adding a lot of cost in getting it processed.

You will need to revisit the calculation of your 'Tenure' field in the second part of the UNION as I couldn't understand what you're trying to do here.

```
USE  ANR_Payroll


SELECT DISTINCT
a.[from]
,[to] As 'TO'
,'***' as 'Total Days Worked'
,Z.EmployeecodeAs 'Employeecode'
,B.LastName
,B.FirstName
,B.Middlename
,B.Levelcode
,Z.[BatchCode] As 'BatchCode' 
,Z.EarningCode As 'Earning Code' 
,Z.Rate As 'Rate'
,Z.Ratetype As 'RateType',
A.[noofunits] / 8 as 'DAYS'
,'' Tenure
,'A' Orderkey 
FROM tblPayrolltransactionEntry as A 
INNER JOIN tblEmployeeMainInfo as B 
    ON a.EmployeeCode = b.EmployeeCode 
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT TOP 1 
                [from]
                , EmployeeCode
                , [to]
                , BatchCode
                , EarningCode
                , Rate
                , RateType
                , noofunits 
                FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].[tblPayrollTransactionEntry]
            ) Z 
    ON A.[from] = Z.[from] 
    AND A.employeecode = Z.EmployeeCode
WHERE B.Employeecode like '%0000011350%'
    AND EarningCode = 'SF' 
    AND PayType     = 'PayOut'  


   UNION ALL 


SELECT
MIN(sub.[from]) 
,MAX(sub.[to])
,'Total Days Worked'
,A.Employeecode
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
,SUM(sub.[DAYS]) as 'DAYS'
,((SUM(NoOfUNits) / 8) / 366) as 'Tenure'
,'B' Orderkey
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        a.[from]
        ,[to] As 'TO'
        ,'***' as 'Total Days Worked'
        ,Z.EmployeecodeAs 'Employeecode'
        ,B.LastName
        ,B.FirstName
        ,B.Middlename
        ,B.Levelcode
        ,Z.[BatchCode] As 'BatchCode' 
        ,Z.EarningCode As 'Earning Code' 
        ,Z.Rate As 'Rate'
        ,Z.Ratetype As 'RateType',
        A.[noofunits] / 8 as 'DAYS'
        ,'' Tenure
        ,'A' Orderkey 
        FROM tblPayrolltransactionEntry as A 
        INNER JOIN tblEmployeeMainInfo as B 
            ON a.EmployeeCode = b.EmployeeCode 
        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT TOP 1 
                        [from]
                        , EmployeeCode
                        , [to]
                        , BatchCode
                        , EarningCode
                        , Rate
                        , RateType
                        , noofunits 
                        FROM [ANR_Payroll].[dbo].[tblPayrollTransactionEntry]
                    ) Z 
            ON A.[from] = Z.[from] 
            AND A.employeecode = Z.EmployeeCode
        WHERE B.Employeecode like '%0000011350%'
            AND EarningCode = 'SF' 
            AND PayType     = 'PayOut'  
    ) sub
```

Comment: The report is ran on a datagrid of a .net I think.That query is came from a stored procedure and I am trying to modify it..the tenure part is just a test for me if i added another field would the system  run as usual, so luckily it run as expected showing the tenure field.Thats why I proved my idea that the query is thrown to a dataset which is the datasource of that datagrid. what i want to rectify now is the summation of the noofunits is not equal total of displayed row. But if there is a better way can please help me. Since our programmer is already resign and his code not turn over to me

Comment: Could you show some data and add the expected output to your original question please. What exactly is the problem with the sum of the data, are you trying to sum the data or are you trying to count the number of rows?

Comment: In addition the original query doesnt have any distinct  a.[from] which result a total of 41 rows, I want to avoid the duplicate transaction that is why use Distinct from.

Comment: Sir Rich Benner I attached an image having the sum of all days..Instead of 413.75 it should be 381.75 only..

Comment: ok, update your question with the exact code that you're using now, are you sure you are using SELECT DISTINCT in your sub query?

Comment: Ok, you'll have to investigate as I don't have your data available to me. Run the second part of the query (after the union) on it's own, see if you get the right answer. If so, remove the SUM functions from the outer select (so that you're not aggregating) and see if the results are correct or not, that will give you a good starting point to go on.